# How to filter Hive data in flutter by data values?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

In Flutter, I using `ValueListenableBuilder` widget to get list of hive data,
and I'm trying to filter my data by data values.

Example:-

```
Key: 1

name(value) : mydata1

des(value) : mydescription1

value(value) : 1
```

here in this example I want to filter data by data value called `value(value)` by help of dropdown,

like:

```
if (value.compareTo(1) == 1){
 print('All First Value Data Showing Result');
}
```

Something like that:

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: msgbox.listenable(),
    builder: (context, box, _) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> raw = box.toMap();
      List list = raw.values.toList();
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          MsgModel msges = list[index];
          return GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: () {},
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
              child: Column(
                children: [
...
```

[ValueListenableBuilder mycode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuFfn.png)

Answer (score 18):

You can simply filter the list using the `where()` function.
Example:

```
list.where((item) => item.value == 1)
    .forEach((item) => print('All First Value Data Showing Result'));
```

This will filter the list and retain objects only where the value is equal to 1.

Or for other people that are using `Box` to retrieve your values you can do like this example:

```
Box<Item> itemBox = Hive.box<Item>("Item");
itemBox.values.where((item) => item.value == 1)
       .forEach((item) => print('All First Value Data Showing Result'));
```

Hope this is what you were searching for.

Answer (score 5):

this is simple code .

```
          var filteredUsers = monstersBox.values
          .where((Monster) => Monster.name == "Vampire")
          .toList();
      print(filteredUsers.length);
```

and this is my class :

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Monster {
  @HiveField(0)
  String? name;
  @HiveField(1)
  int? level;
  Monster(this.name, this.level);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Edit Your Model Object ,you will need hive model key soon and later.
For that I have some kind of filtering keys specific and use those to read data. Do not use `index` from `box.values` because it can misleading issue when you delete or update some data on a model like `box.putAt(index,updatedModel)` or `box.deleteAt(index,toBeDeletedModel)` when multi selecting models.

```
dbBox = Box<YourModel>();
final filterdList =
            dbBox.values.where((element) => element.isFavourite!);

final filteredKeys = filterdList.map((element) {
         return dbBox.keyAt(dbBox.values.toList().indexOf(element));
        }).toList();
List<Widget> myLists = filteredKeys.map((key) { 
          final currentModel = dbBox.get(key);
          return YourModelCardWidget(modelKey : key , model : currentModel);
        }).toList();
 // then, you can use that key below ..
 // dbBox.put(key, updatedModel) ( Update ) 
 // dbBox.delete(key, currentModel)  ( Delete )
```