# How to filter hive data in a listview

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-hive

I'm using a ValueListenableBuilder to get a ListView of NoteData stored in a hive box.

```
SizedBox(
              width: 900,
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<Box<NoteData>>(
                  valueListenable: Boxes.getNotes().listenable(),
                  builder: (context, box, _) {
                    final notes = box.values.toList().cast<NoteData>();
                    // var _filteredNotes
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: notes.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return NoteView(note: notes[index]);
                        });
                  }),
            ),
```

Now I want to filter the displayed results with the onChanged callback of a TextField. How do I do that?

```
SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 242,
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: ((value) {}), // (value) => _runFilter(value),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Notiz suchen',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                )
```

I found some tutorials on how to filter a listview, but I don't know how to implement that in my project, while working with a hive box.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform some conditioning on values retrived from hive . More information with example: [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272936/how-to-filter-hive-data-in-flutter-by-data-values). Then just uptade /redraw your ListView